# What is the furthest object from which fermion rays were detected?

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, cosmic-rays

What is the furthest object from which non-electromagnetic cosmic rays were detected?

Answer (score 2):

For example, [neutrinos from a Supernova](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_astronomy) was detected in 1987 (and it seems that was the only observation of this kind). [Cosmic rays from outer space](http://helios.gsfc.nasa.gov/gcr.html) are also observed, but I don't know if their source can be identified precisely.

Comment: *"but I don't know if their source can be identified precisely"* At ultra-high energies there it is possible to roughly attribute some instances to active galaxtic nuclei at distances rather farther than the LMC.

Comment: There are some serious theoretical problems with the idea of charged particles traveling over significant chunks of the universe. If I recall correctly, the cosmic microwave background at those velocities starts looking like hits from high-energy gamma rays, slowing the charged particles down. Then there are magnetic fields that curve the particles in interesting ways. It's a tough question for which I don't believe there is a consensus answer.

Comment: @TerryBollinger that is why gamma rays and neutrinos are popular with astrophysicists. Neutrinos are fermions, though.http://arxiv.org/abs/0808.0735

Comment: Concur, yes indeed! Gamma exploration is hard mostly in the engineering sense, with plenty of still-unexplored potential as we move more into space. For neutrinos it's just too bad those incredibly common little puppies aren't easier to spot. Still, the progress in neutrino detectors been pretty amazing also, even if the detectors mostly make whales look like minnows.